# where to put polymer element references for included sub-dependencies

Tags: polymer

If I create a new element in polymer, one that say uses google map web components - do I put the reference to

`<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">`

in the element's own template, or should I put them all in the elements.html or the main index.html?

Comment: Html Imports are deduped, so you don't have to worry about where you are putting your imports.

Comment: Oddly, if I put that link in the element file itself, it's doesn't render, so I have to put it in the main index.html.  Additionally, trying to append a google-map-marker gives an error of google is not found.  Why do I have to hard code a reference to the google map script even though it's already referenced by the google maps component?

Comment: what about js dependencies in polymer?  Is it best practice to put it all in index.html or to use something like require.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "[Create a reusable element](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/reusableelements.html)" guide will walk you through the process, using [`<seed-element>`](https://github.com/polymerelements/seed-element) as the starting point.

The correct approach is to import elements from within your own element's HTML file (though not within the `<template>`), using a relative path that's one level up. The example from the guide is `<link rel="import" href="../paper-button/paper-button.html">` at the top-level of the element's HTML file.